# 404 Not Found, but route exist in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpstorm, laravel-5.4

I'm using PhpStorm. I can run and open the `index.php`, but when I want to press submit button (post sign in), its display 404 not found.

Web server Apache 2.4 running on Windows 10.

This is my home

[image: index.php]

This is my route

[image: web.php]

Comment: I think you should probably go through the documentation of Laravel. Go through it https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation

Comment: What is the URL that you see in the browser's address bar when this page does not work?

Comment: You should include exact error and code of the form you try to submit

Comment: another thing even though it looks not to be that here :
if you have a route defined like /planning/{weeknumber} and then another like /planning/day, you can't reach the /planning/day unless you declare it before the other, because 'day' will be passed as a variable to the 1st route, and you might get a 404, depending on how your controller manages it.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Which route is the form sent to?

Comment: I was finally able to solve the problem by running the command  `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 140):

The first thing I suggest trying is running `php artisan route:list` from the command line (from your project root directory).  This will list all the routes that Laravel can register and if there are any errors, usually they will show up here.

The second thing I suggest is to ensure that the URL matches route.  I can't tell you how many times I've tried to figure out why my route was returning a 404 simply because my form was posting to something like `/insertStudent` when my route was defined as `/admin/insertStudent`

The third thing I suggest is to ensure the method you are calling exists.  Are your methods really called `postSignIn` and `postInsertStudent` and not simply `SignIn` and `InsertStudent`?  Keep in mind that both the URL and method names are case sensitive and should match where you define the route, the URL that is being called, and the method that is receiving the request.

Finally if all that checks out, one last thing I might suggest you try is running `php artisan route:clear`.  This resets the route cache.

Comment: i copy existing directory to new, also run `php artisan route:clear` but still page not found at new directory but on old directory page is found. any idea ?

Comment: @anunixercoder, I suggest starting a new question being very specific about what you've tried and what error you're seeing.  As mentioned, run php artisan route:list - you won't see what you want through the browser until route:list runs successfully with the expected output.

Comment: Only other point to suggest is to ensure you are not using "$" in your routes. I tried using /users/edit_project_access/{$userId}/{$projectId} which also gave me a 404. Check that your URLs dont have $ signs as such: /users/edit_project_access/{userId}/{projectId}

Comment: May I suggest to add `check route ordering` ? That was what I did wrong

Comment: Oh yes @ChristoffX that was it in my case. I had 'contacts/ads_off/{$contactId}'. Didn't see it before your comment. Thanks!

Comment: Another reason is: If you use Route::resource('xxx'.... then you can not use Route::get('xxx/test',...
This leads to a 404 error. The solution here would be a different path. For Example: Route::get('test',...

Comment: On top of that, I have found it a good practice to optimize your app `php artisan optimize`

Comment: In my case I had a mismatching `APP_URL` in the `.env`-File.

Answer (score 72):

Please make sure you have Apache configured with the following information in `/path/to/apache2/installation/conf/httpd.conf`

```
<Directory "path/to/laravel/project/public">
    Allowoverride All
</Directory>
```

For the `.htaccess` file located in the `public/` folder, make sure it includes the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine On

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then enable the Apache `mod_rewrite` module:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? I don't think that `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is present on Windows. Additionally, which parts are needed and why? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer

Comment: ```sudo a2enmod rewrite```  fixed my issue thank you

Comment: Feel like a rookie moving to laravel - missed the mod_rewrite - Thanks!

Answer (score 57):

I had the same Issue & resolved it by changing the way Routes were ordered.

Before:

```
Route::get('/p/{post}', 'PostsController@show');
Route::get('/p/create', 'PostsController@create');
```

After: (and that 404 disappeared)

```
Route::get('/p/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::get('/p/{post}', 'PostsController@show');
```

Comment: Taking the same example you have given, I think the reason is,
If we had /p/{post} before, route is matching the request to /p/create to /p/{post} with create as the variable value to {post} .

Comment: I find this especially true for resource routes. If you need to define an additional route to existing resource routes, you must declare it in your web.php BEFORE the resource routes, otherwise it will throw a 404 error for that route.

Comment: This solved my problem but in my case:
`Route::get('p/something', [PostController::class, 'something']);` should be ordered before `Route::resource('p', PostController::class);`

Comment: Same as @user16806454, Route::resource had to be at the end of the group

Answer (score 33):

try

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

and then type this and see whether your route exists in the list

```
php artisan route:list
```

and also in Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php check post routes are allowed

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware {

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'api/*'
    ];

}
```

Comment: Thanks, php artisan route:cache saved me!

Answer (score 12):

One more possibility...  If the controller has Laravel's findOrFail() method, and the item sought is not found, a 404 page is returned.

Comment: I had this issue cause of the cookies, some old stuff in the cookies were being used the findOrFail causing a global 404 everywhere.

Answer (score 12):

I fixed this error on **Larvel 8.34** by doing these two steps

1. `php artisan route:clear`
2. Go to browser and (assuming your URL is localhost:8000) type `localhost:8000/clear-cache`. it should show "**Done**".

The issue should be fixed afterward.

Comment: Dude I spent like an hour trying to figure it out what was going on! All new routes failed til ran the `route:clear` command, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This is old question but is active yet.
for windows users if you using **CAPITAL** characters (upper-case letter) in your project folder you should using same in your browser.
If your project is in `"c:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\"` you should using `MyProject` as url instead of `myproject`
for example in the above project (MyProject) following route:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return 'welcome to dashboard!';
});
```

will work if you use:

```
http://MyProject/dashboard
```

but is better using lowercase characters in directories

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and fixed by following

I have edit .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /path/of/project/folder/
# change above to your site i.e.,  RewriteBase /whatever/public/
```

Hope it will work for you

Comment: It worked for me !
I had an alias and was working on subfolder of my localhost. Only homepage was working.
After adding RewriteBase /myalias/ in htaccess file of public folder, my routes started working !

Comment: felling well, it was working for you too. :)

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget the order of your routes. For example, if you want to go to `/path/second` and have the following routes registered:

```
Route::get('/path/{dynamic_second}', 'Controller@actionDynamic');

Route::get('/path/{dynamic_second}/{dynamic_third}', 'Controller@third');

Route::get('/path/second', 'Controller@action');
```

This will break, as `second` is consumed by `/path/{dynamic_second}`.

If you want to access `/path/second`, you have to have your routes listed like so:

```
Route::get('/path/second', 'Controller@action');

Route::get('/path/{dynamic_second}', 'Controller@actionDynamic');

Route::get('/path/{dynamic_second}/{dynamic_third}', 'Controller@third');
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you added correct `Accept` header.

In my case I tried to access `api` endpoints and each time recieved  404 resource not found.
When I've added `Accept: application/json` header I got response from matched route

Comment: This method allowed me to see Exception error

Answer (score 4):

I was going crazy about my routes not working and here is also a quick fix. I had the following route: 
`users/{user}/user-detail-changes/{user-detail-change}/update-status` 
The fix was to rename parameters. Laravel doesn't accept minus character  `-`.
Rather than that you have to use  `camelCase` or  underscore (`_`) variable naming conventions. 
So it has to be like: 
`users/{user}/user-detail-changes/{userDetailChange}/update-status`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are not running another laravel project on the same port.

Answer (score 2):

make sure, the url passed is equal in your route. check the parameters and action in the form. To get clear answer post your mvc

Answer (score 2):

When at the time of website hosting there is the problem 404 Not Found Error on requested pages. At That time there is only home page is work fine. And if i request another page for e.g. mydomain.com/any_page then it sends me to the 404 Not Found Error Then i looked at my controller files and other routes files to solve the problem. Finally i think there is absent of the .htaccess file When i just added the .htaccess file to the same folder of the index.php of the laravel project then it juts works file.

Conclusion

By adding the .htaccess file at the same folder location of the index.php it solves the 404 page not found error in my laravel Project.

Comment: When changing the index.php file route (for example bringing it out of 'Public' folder), you should change the route of .htaccess either.

Answer (score 2):

this can also happen if, for an API route, the Content-Type is not set to application/json when validation fails for a given request. This was the issue in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently and I thought I was using a Reserved word, which I couldn't find in the [list of reserved words of PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.php).

Originally my **Routes/web.php** was:

```
Route::post('sysinfo/store',['as'=>'sysinfo.store', 'uses'=>'SysinfoController@store']);
```

After I changed to another name as shown bellow, it worked!

```
Route::post('newsysinfo/store',['as'=>'newsysinfo.store',   'uses'=>'SysinfoController@store']);
```

What's weird is that I have other working routes such as:

```
Route::get('sysinfo/',['as'=>'sysinfo.index',   'uses'=>'SysinfoController@index']);
Route::post('sysinfo/{sysinfo}',['as'=>'sysinfo.update',   'uses'=>'SysinfoController@update']);
Route::get('sysinfo/create',['as'=>'sysinfo.create',   'uses'=>'SysinfoController@create']);
Route::get('sysinfo/{id}/edit',['as'=>'sysinfo.edit',   'uses'=>'SysinfoController@edit']);
Route::get('sysinfo/{sysinfo}/destroy',['as'=>'sysinfo.destroy',   'uses'=>'SysinfoController@destroy']);
```

Although it's not an explanation of the causes of the problem, perhaps this workaround can help you.

Comment: I wager that your post route for `sysinfo/{sysinfo}` was answering all of your attempts to hit `sysinfo/store`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [webwizard02](https://github.com/webwizard02) in [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/1015#issuecomment-522825626):

> Hello! I also encountered this problem before. Please check your Apache's httpd.conf file. Make sure that you enabled the `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` by removing the `#` from the start line of the code.
>
> And also change inside the httpd.conf from Require all denied to Require all granted, AllowOverride All, and Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
>
> Like This:
> [image: Capture]

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was issue with .htaccess file.
Make sure you have the .htaccess in public_html folder.
I downloaded this file from one server but the dot(.) was removed by the downloader. Then when I uploaded in another server, the dot(.) was missing and I got 404.

My .htaccess looks like below:

```
# disable directory browsing, but specific file browsing is possible, e.g. /js/bootstrap.js
        
    Options ExecCGI Includes IncludesNOEXEC SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
#To set which file will be acted as index file: DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>


<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

# deny from some DDoS attackers ip
# deny from 69.171.251.0/24


# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# This domain inherits the “PHP” package.
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Answer (score 1):

## On Centos

1. Set the proper permission for the application files and directories.

   ```sh
   chown -R apache.apache /var/www/YOUR_LARAVEL_APP
   chmod -R 755 /var/www/YOUR_LARAVEL_APP
   chmod -R 755 /var/www/YOUR_LARAVEL_APP/storage
   ```
2. SELinux enabled systems also run the below command to allow write on storage directory.

   ```sh
   chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/myLaravelApp/storage
   ```

Finally, access your Laravel application in a web browser.

Note: If you are using Nginx use `nginx.nginx` instead of `apache.apache`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried almost all the solutions above but it didn't work. So I decided to change the route name to something else and it worked.

e.g:
This was not working:

```
Route::get('product/show/{id}', [SiteController::class, 'showProduct'])->name('product.show');
```

This worked:

```
Route::get('raslimali/show/{id}', [SiteController::class, 'showProduct'])->name('product.show');
```

Comment: Habari Did you ever find out why it was not working  the only change was product to raslimali.   I think this was the issue  --> One more possibility... If the controller has Laravel's findOrFail() method, and the item sought is not found, a 404 page is returned.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to share my experience when it comes to this type of 404 error with an existing route.

In my case the problem was the length of the query, I had to increase the maxQueryString.

[This post help me](https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/iis/iis-changing-maxquerystring-and-maxurl)

> Query string length: By default, Microsoft IIS accepts a maximum query
> string length of 2048 characters. If IIS receives a query string that
> is longer than 2048 characters, it will generate a 404.15: Query

> String Too Long error URL length: Like the query string, each browser
> has a limit on the length of the URL it supports. For example,
> Internet Explorer accepts a maximum URL length of 2083. If the URL
> length exceeds the limit, you'll get a 404.14: URL too long error.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the server port worked for me after trying several fixes all to no avail. I was running on loalhost:3000 and changed to localhost:4000. I think this might have to do with some memory cahe

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2020**

There are many case happened above, I've once more case I met a long time but I still forget and sometimes I dont know why. This is some url patterns is the same, example **abc.com/c/{get_an_id}** and **abc.com/c/get_text**. You can change order but only first can run, 404 for the second url.

Comment: This should be its own question. But the issue is the path with the parameter ({get_an_id}) needs to come second. Otherwise "get_text" would be sent as the parameter value. If it is already second and getting a 404, it's probably because a lookup is failing (.i.e abc.com/c/54 returns 404 because there is no id that matches 54 in your DB)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help someone, I fix this problem changing the order from my routes in laravel.

in my case i had the route ..users/crea --> 404 error

```html
 Route::get('users', 'Admin\UserController@index')->name('users.index')
 Route::put('users/{user}', 'Admin\UserController@update')->name('users.update')
 **Route::get('users/crea', 'Admin\UserController@crea')->name('users.crea');**
```

and to fixed

```html
 Route::get('users', 'Admin\UserController@index')->name('users.index')
 *Route::get('users/crea', 'Admin\UserController@crea')->name('users.crea');*
 Route::put('users/{user}', 'Admin\UserController@update')->name('users.update')
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using Homestead, and after being stuck for quite some time trying everything that there was to try, what finally worked was re-checking my Hosts file (`/etc/hosts` on *nix systems), verifying my Homestead.yaml configuration file, and running the 'provision' command on the Homestead Vagrant Box.

The provision seems to have cleared some caches previously held or deployed the currently working site, honestly can't understand what changed since the databases were working and unit tests were passing.

But leaving it here in case it can help somebody out.

Answer (score 0):

one thing i would like to add for user's who use nginx server and have configured server blocks(virtual hosts). check which server block is activated in your nginx conf files.

also in /etc/hosts file check whether you are using correct url to your server block or not.

also check your IP address there.

Plus all other point that are mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a permissions issue. User I was logged in with didnt have the necessary assigned role that gave the required permission to view said URL/section.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was mistakenly overriding the crsf token on form submit and it was throwing a 404 instead of actually giving a more meaningful message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The reason was that i was making https requests but i did not set-up https configuration in apache vhost. So apache was sending 404.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was the final solution:

```
chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
```

Answer (score 0):

In the local environment, you have to change your port with the following command:

```
php artisan serve --port your_digit_port
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a filename with extension as a parameter as you can see below:

```
Route::get('/attachment/{filename}', function() {
    //
});
```

I always get 404 error when I tried to access following URL from the browser:

`http://localhost/attachment/filename.ext`

After many hours of struggle and an advise from a friend, I finally found out that the filename.ext is treated differently in Laravel (as physical file), hence I need to change the filename parameter to either of one below:

1. using base64encode(filename), or
2. create parameter to split the filename into filename_only and extension (e.g. myfilename.txt into myfilename and txt)

To split the filename:

```
Route::get('/attachment/{filename_only}/extension/{extension}', function() {
    //
});
```

Hope this helps as an alternative answers.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 with Laravel 10 and Postman I had a similar problem.
In my postman I had a variable base_url which ends with "/" so my base url was http://localhost:8000/
And in the request I had a line like this:
{{base_url}}/api/some_endpoint

Because of two "/" symbols I had a 404 error saying that there is no api/some_route_name, but no mention about double "/"
I spent about an hour to find that. Just keep in mind this case too

Answer (score 0):

In my case I review all the above answers. I check my route I check my Controller everything seems fine to me and all old routes works fine but when I try to add any new route it gave **404 not found**. I try clear routes and strange thing code works on my local machine (windows, wamp) and also on development environment (Ubuntu, Nginx)
Problem happen on Staging and Live Environment
I Run these commands

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

but still same not found
at last I restart **Nginx** and everything works fine.
below is the command to restart Nginx on ubuntu

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

##### Verions:

- Laravel 8.0
- Php 8.1
- with Ubuntu and Nginx

Answer (score 0):

My problem was resolved my clearing config cache by `php artisan config:clear`.

Answer (score -1):

dontforget, the url is sensitive case to the folder name

Comment: Can you explain further what this means? How did you guess that there is a problem using cases? How to solve this?

Comment: if your htdocs subfolder contain capital case, then you must call the url with capital case.ie. folder is AvenGers inside the htdocs, then must call localhost/AvenGers

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem but the solution is that simple :

go to cmd and tap cd #your project path#

then tap php artisan serve

copy the link of the server given (http://127.0.0.1:8000) to your browser, and it'll work!