# Laravel 404 page not found, route exists

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to navigate to my "productdetail" page but it givdes me a 404. The route to productdetail does exists. I am trying to give product information from shop to productdetail

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function shopindex()
    {
        $productsOTs = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM wiz.productimages WHERE Afkorting = 'PPI' LIMIT 83, 3"));
        return view('shop', compact('productsOTs'));
    }

    public function productdetail(Product $Product)
    {   
        return view('Products.productdetail', compact('productsOT'));

    }

}
```

My shop page link to productdetail:

```
           @foreach ($productsOTs as $productsOT)
                <div class="card ot-product" id="heightwidthfix">
                    <img class="card-img-top cardstop" src="{{$productsOT->imagelink}}" alt="Card image cap" id="myshopmodal1" height="400px" width="300px">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{$productsOT->Productomschrijving}}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="/shop/productdetail/{{ $productsOT->Productcode }}" class="card-link">Bekijk hier het product</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('/shop', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@shopindex']);
Route::get('/shop/productdetail/{product}', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@productdetail']);
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Please show the error screen?

Comment: Are you sure that your `productdetail` view located in the `Products` folder? please check carefully

Comment: is your `Productcode` the unique identifier column of your products table?

Comment: return view('Products.productdetail', compact('productsOT'));  what is productsOT here ?

Comment: Yes my productdetail view is located in the Products foler

Comment: productsOT  is the  product information that i want to pass to productdetail

Comment: From your code sample @slekniws 'productsOT' is not defined. Is this intentionally removed from the snippet for brevity?

Comment: No its not intentionally, how is it not defined?

Comment: Is `Productcode` the primary key of `Procuduct`? Is it defined as such?

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` to see if your route is listed there. Does your other route `/shop` work? What version of Laravel are you using, those look like L4 routes

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.7, /shop does work. Here is my route list: \                                ```| | GET|HEAD  | shop/productdetail/{product}  |  | App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@productdetail```

Comment: It might sound obvious, but.. Have you tried putting the `/shop` route on the bottom? :)

Comment: yes , still a 404

Comment: I had issue with .htaccess, please have alook at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64828062/1938507

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to put a name for your route

```
Route::get('/shop/productdetail/{product}', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@productdetail'])->name('show-product');
```

then call it through it's name:

```
<a href="{{route('show-product',$productsOT->Productcode) }}" class="card-link">Bekijk hier het product</a>
```

This will might solve your problem otherwise the problem is not on the route.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
<a href="/shop/productdetail/{{ $productsOT->Productcode }}" class="card-link">Bekijk hier het product</a>
```

into

```
<a href="{{ url('shop/productdetail/'.$productsOT->Productcode) }}" class="card-link">Bekijk hier het product</a>
```

This is the minor mistake. Change this, I hope it is helpful. Thanks

Comment: Also remove middleware in your route because you add middleware in your controller constructor. And use simple route like
Route::get('/shop/productdetail/{product}', 'ProductsController@productdetail');

Answer (score 1):

Hey buddy first thing to do this go to your command

- `php artisan route:clear`
- `php artisan optimize`

but I found something, I got worry in your code.

I prefer you 2 choices to solve this one

- `URL('/shop/productdetail/'.{{$id_here}})`
- or add router name in your routes. `->name('shop_productdetails);`
  then use this in your blade `{{route('shop_productdetails',$id)}}`

You're Welcome buddy

Answer (score 0):

Please run this commend

> php artisan route:cache

and also

> php artisan cache:clear

Comment: It gives me a error :   LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.

Comment: @slekniws yes, same for me. any solution ?

Comment: please check `routes/api.php` file. Laravel adds a default auth api route to above file. comment that code in that file and error will gone.

Comment: this will be the code `Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following way

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->get('/shop/productdetail/{product}', 'ProductsController@productdetail');
```

I usually prefer to group the middleware so as to overcome writing it again and again by the following way

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        /** Dashboard */
        Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard');
        /**Customer */
        Route::get('/customers', 'AdminController@customerListing');
});
```

Comment: Stil gives me a 404.

Comment: Can you please add the 404 image. I think the view page might be right.

Comment: Even there is a chance that the testing project and working project might be wrong

Comment: We made our own error page:                           
`@extends('layouts.errorLayout')

@section('code', '404')
@section('title', __('Page Not Found'))
@section('homebutton')
<a href="{{ url('/home') }}">
    <button class="bg-transparent text-kuijpers-blue font-bold uppercase tracking-wide py-3 px-6 border-2 border-grey-light hover:border-grey rounded-lg">
        {{ __('Go Home') }}
    </button>
</a>
@endsection  
@section('message', __('Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.'))`

Comment: I dont know how to put the code beneath each other, its not very clear this way ..

Comment: @slekniws on the web right click on the links ie inspect as HTML and see if the URL is coming properly whether the product ID is getting set or not.

Comment: @ Channaveer Hakari  Yes it loads, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/productdetail/3581635`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your route parameter that you have passed that is not appropriate pass

```
<a href="/shop/productdetail/{{ $productsOT->relevant_id_colunm_name }}" class="card-link">Bekijk hier het product</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with .htaccess.
I uploaded, but it was somehow missing!
I faced some other problems, everything is documented with my .htaccess file content here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64828062/1938507

Answer (score 0):

why are u doing `$productsOt->ProductCode` instead of `$productsOt->id`? If you need to get using the `ProductCode`. Use

```
Route::get('/shop/productdetail/{product:ProductCode}', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@productdetail']);
```

if your column name is ProductCode

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```php
<a href="url('/shop/productdetail', [$productsOT->Productcode])" class="card-link">Bekijk hier het product</a>
```

If this does not work, try

```php
php artisan route:clear
```

If that does not work, try

```php
php artisan optimize
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

You are using the `Route Binding` feature but, not totally valid because the route segment and function parameter must be identical and this does not apply to what you did where your route segment is `product` and function parameter is `Product`, and this is invalid approach and when you pass the product id as a parameter, Laravel searches in the `products` table with the given id, and because the given id does not exist in the database Laravel trigger this page So, your code must be like so

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/shop/productdetail/{product}', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@productdetail']);
```

**ProductsController.php**

```
public function productdetail($product)
{   
    $products = \App\Models\Product::where("id", $product)->get();

    return view('Products.productdetail', compact('products'));
}
```

you may want to search with another column name than `id` so you must specify the other column name that you wish to search with as Laravel says [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#customizing-the-key)

### Solution 2

If you register these routes in a new route file other than `web.php`, you must define this file in `RouteServiceProvider.php` as Laravel says [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#the-default-route-files)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a little bit tricky:

What is happening :

Your Laravel application is currently using an out-dated routes cached file located in app/bootstrap/routes-x.php file instead of your routes files located in app/routes directory.

**The solution :**

1. manualy delete app/bootstrap/routes-x.php file.
2. in your app/routes (api.php or console.php ... )  routes files replace any route that is using a closure with controllerName@functionName

   example of route using a closure :

   > Route::get('/route-using-closure', function() {
   > return 'Hello World'; });

   Replace by:

   > Route::get('/route-using-closure', 'controllerName@functionName');
3. Only run php artisan route:cache in dev mode or any other caching command to avoid this errors.