# laravel 6.9 localhost keep loading than Not found

Tags: laravel, localhost

I download a fresh laravel project from someone for testing.

After setting up and running using php artisan serve, the locahost (http://localhost:8000/) keep loading slowly then It shows message 404 not found.

I have tried to solve using command line php artisan serve --port=1010 and run http://localhost:1010/ on broswer but It didn't work.

And I also used php -S localhost:8000 -t public or php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public after run localhost:8000 on broswer but it still didn't work.

any idea?

Comment: Do you have your xampp or wampp started?

Comment: @ClarisseJoyce yes it has started but I think I don't need them as I use php artisan serve to run laravel.

Comment: Could you paste your web/route.php file

Comment: @FouèdMoussi it has only one route Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Comment: And what about your public/index.php file ?

Comment: I solved it by following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52802757/401902

Answer (score 0):

Check once there is storage/framework/cache/data and storage/framework/sessions directory created or not, if those doesn't exist then create manually.