# Laravel route not found when route exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I try to access my laravel site I get this error in the console.

```
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
[Mon Nov 16 10:39:15 2020] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Route [home] not defined. in /Users/threeaccents/code/src/gitlab.com/few/bodylove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:389
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/threeaccents/code/src/gitlab.com/few/bodylove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(822): Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator->route('home', Array, true)
#1 /Users/threeaccents/code/src/gitlab.com/few/bodylove/storage/framework/views/e071ac62e490c49233841ae8b6b3906075bc0187.php(6): route('home')
#2 /Users/threeaccents/code/src/gitlab.com/few/bodylove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(43): include('/Users/threeacc...')
#3 /Users/threeaccents/code/src/gitlab.com/few/bodylove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Users/threeacc...', Array)
#4 /Users/threeaccents/code/src/gitlab.com/few/bodylove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(142): Illuminate\Vi in /Users/threeaccents/code/src/gitlab.com/few/bodylove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php on line 389
[Mon Nov 16 10:39:15 2020] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Route [home] not defined. in /Users/threeaccents/code/src/gitlab.com/few/bodylove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:389
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/threeaccents/code/src/gitlab.com/few/bodylove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(822): Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator->route('home', Array, true)
#1 /Users/threeaccents/code/src/gitlab.com/few/bodylove/storage/framework/views/e071ac62e490c49233841ae8b6b3906075bc0187.php(6): route('home')
#2 /Users/threeaccents/code/src/gitlab.com/few/bodylove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(43): include('/Users/threeacc...')
#3 /Users/threeaccents/code/src/gitlab.com/few/bodylove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Users/threeacc...', Array)
#4 /Users/threeaccents/code/src/gitlab.com/few/bodylove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(142): Illuminate\Vi in /Users/threeaccents/code/src/gitlab.com/few/bodylove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php on line 389
```

But route home is clearly defined. I even set it at the top of my route file to make sure nothing else was overriding it.

```
routes/web.php
<?php

// New Home Page for App
Route::get('/', 'Web\HomeController@index')->name('home');

...
```

with `php artisan route:list`

```
+--------+----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method                                 | URI                                                                                        | Name                                       | Action                                                                                         | Middleware                                                                                                                                                                        |
+--------+----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD                               | .well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association                                  |                                            | App\Http\Controllers\Web\ApplePayDomainVerificationController                                  | web                                                                                                                                                                               |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | /                                                                                          | home                                       | App\Http\Controllers\Web\HomeController@index                                                  | web                                                                                                                                                                               |
```

**Update**

I've cleared route cache, deleted vendor folder, re-installed PHP but nothing seems to solve the issue.

I've tried it on my work laptop (same setup) and everything works. It seems to be an issue with my current station but I'm not sure what would be causing it. I'm using PHP 7.2 on a mac os 10.14.4. Laravel 5.7

I also thought maybe it was an overall system issue but if I create a new laravel project everything works as expected so it does seem to be a project specific issue.

Comment: And about your controller folder structure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [404 Not Found, but route exist in Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715106/404-not-found-but-route-exist-in-laravel-5-4)

Comment: Very interesting.. Do you use opcache? Or any other php level cache system? And I would suggest you to fully `rm -rf` delete generated cache folder. Maybe it's just messed up and can't override it..

Comment: Try using `url("/")` instead of the route helper to determine behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with my apache config. It seems on my latest brew update apache got updated and the config file changed a bit. I had to change

```
#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -2):

**You can remove name('home'), because error is Route [home] not defined**

```
<?php
// New Home Page for App
Route::get('/', 'Web\HomeController@index');
```