# Deleting record data in Laravel is not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am a newbie in Laravel programming. I have searched so many resources about delete functions but it doesn't work. When I click my delete button, it only shows 404 NOT FOUND. I am using Laravel 7.0. Hopefully, you can help me resolve it. Thank you!
[image]

Here

```
/**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $student = Student::find($id);
        $student->delete();
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Here is my Route:

```
Route::get('/delete/{id}','StudentController@destroy');
```

Here is my View:

```
<table class="table thead-light">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Mã sinh viên</th>
      <th scope="col">Khối</th>
      <th scope="col">Tên lớp</th>
      <th scope="col">Họ và Tên</th>
      <th scope="col">Thầy/Cô giáo chủ nhiệm</th>
      <th scope="col">Tính năng</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($students as $student)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ $student->id }}</th>
        <td>{{ $student->student_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $student->grade }}</td>
        <td>{{ $student->class }}</td>
        <td>{{ $student->fullname }}</td>
        <td>{{ $student->head_teacher }}</td>
        <td id="functions">           
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Xem hồ sơ</a> 
            <a href="{{ url('/edit/'.$student->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning">Sửa</a>
            <a href='delete/{{ $student->id }}' class="btn btn-danger">Xóa</a>
        </td>
    </tr>    
    @endforeach  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Try using `Route::delete()`. You are sending a GET request to a method that expects a DELETE request. [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#available-router-methods)

Comment: `<a href='delete/{{ $student->id }}'`, try it with a prefixed slash, `<a href='/delete/{{ $student->id }}'`.

Answer (score 0):

Another route might be overriding your delete route.

For delete operations, you sould be using a HTTP `Delete` request instead of `Get`.

```php
Route::delete('/delete/{id}','StudentController@destroy');
```

```
<form action="/delete/{{ $student->id }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but the problem still occurs "404 NOT FOUND"

Answer (score 0):

Your link for deleting is incorrect. You should use named routes.

For your Route

```
Route::get('/delete/{id}','StudentController@destroy')->name('delete.student');
```

For the link in the View

```
<a href='{{ route('delete.student', $student->id) }}' class="btn btn-danger">Xóa</a>
```

Consider changing your edit link as well. Try not to use url() for links, use named routes.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, but it raise an exception "Route [delete.student] not defined. (View: D:\Xampp\htdocs\ems_project\resources\views\studentlists.blade.php)"

Comment: Try clearing your route cache. It should not say not defined if you have it in your route.php file

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found the solution to my problem. I have just made reference to this article: [404 Not Found, but route exist in Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715106/404-not-found-but-route-exist-in-laravel-5-4/52802757). In a nutshell, I should use "php artisan route:clear" and "php artisan route:list".