# Laravel 8 Route not defined even route is defined successfully

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

The error is :

> Route [product.cart] not defined.

Here is the route

```php
Route::get('/cart' , CartComponent::class , 'store')->name('product.cart');
```

this is line of view where I want that route View Page `shop-component.balde.php`

```
<a href="#" class="btn add-to-cart" wire:click.prevent="store({{$product->id }} , '{{$product->name}}' , {{$product->regular_price}} )">Add To Cart</a>
```

and this one is the Shop Component code

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use App\Models\Product;
use Cart;

class ShopComponent extends Component
{
    public function store($product_id , $product_name , $product_price)
    {
        Cart::add($product_id , $product_name , 1 , $product_price)->associate('App\Models\Product');
        session()->flash('success_message' , 'Item Successfully Add');
        return redirect()->route('product.cart');
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        $products = Product::paginate(12);
        return view('livewire.shop-component',['products' => $products])->layout('layouts.base');
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any name prefix? Can you share all the routes/web (or api.php) file. Do you see your route calling `php artisan route:list`

Comment: no i dont name any prefix!

Comment: the second question??

Comment: i didn;t share my all routes beacause characters are too long

Comment: when i run the command php artisan route:list , i didn;t see the product.cart route

Comment: run `php artisan optimize:clear` in case you cached the routes. This will clear all cache

Comment: sorry my english is weak

Comment: Then that's why the route is not existing. Try `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: php artisan optimize:clear and it works. thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715106/404-not-found-but-route-exist-in-laravel-5-4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [404 Not Found, but route exist in Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715106/404-not-found-but-route-exist-in-laravel-5-4)

Comment: did you try to encapsulate it like `[CartComponent::class , 'store']`