Route inside a prefix group gives 404 error
I'm using Laravel 11.27.2 and PHP 8.2 and I have noticed that some routes inside a prefix group gives me a 404 error, but if I try move the route outside the prefix group, the route magically works without any type of errors.
Also, if I also move the corrupted route on top the other routes inside the prefix group it works.
I've tried also the command php artisan route:clear but nothing changed.
Instead with the command php artisan route:list the routes are being listed correctly (Route list).
This one doesn't work:
Route::prefix('giveaway')->name('giveaway.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
    Route::post('/store/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
    Route::get('/thank-you', [GiveawayController::class, 'thankYou'])->name('thankYou');
    Route::get('/terms-and-conditions/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'privacyAndTerms'])->name('termsAndConditions');
    Route::get('/privacy-policy/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'privacyAndTerms'])->name('privacyPolicy');
    Route::get('/history', [GiveawayController::class, 'index'])->name('history');
});

This will work:
Route::prefix('giveaway')->name('giveaway.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/history', [GiveawayController::class, 'index'])->name('history'); //Changed position
    Route::get('/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
    Route::post('/store/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
    Route::get('/thank-you', [GiveawayController::class, 'thankYou'])->name('thankYou');
    Route::get('/terms-and-conditions/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'privacyAndTerms'])->name('termsAndConditions');
    Route::get('/privacy-policy/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'privacyAndTerms'])->name('privacyPolicy');
});

This will also work:
Route::prefix('giveaway')->name('giveaway.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
    Route::post('/store/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
    Route::get('/thank-you', [GiveawayController::class, 'thankYou'])->name('thankYou');
    Route::get('/terms-and-conditions/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'privacyAndTerms'])->name('termsAndConditions');
    Route::get('/privacy-policy/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'privacyAndTerms'])->name('privacyPolicy');
});

Route::get('/history', [GiveawayController::class, 'index'])->name('history'); //Outside the route group

The corrupted routes are /history and /thank-you.
I would like to figure out why it's happening such a strange thing.
If helps I'm using Apache as HTTP Server and this is my .htaccess:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php82” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php82 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

I solved the puzzle, the problem was the route '/{id}' where there was no type of constraint and consequently, being the first route in the group, it was chosen first and did not check if other routes existed.
SOLUTION:
1. Move the route to last in that prefix;
2. Add a constraint with regex expressions on the route for the parmeter with ->where();

Well, you've got a route with only a parameter '/{id}', if you change that to '/show/{id}' it will work. now that route matches the /history url.

This is happening cause /{id} and /history are same URL pattern, to solve this issue you can change your route like this Route::get('/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'show'])->where(['id' => '[0-9]+'])->name('show');. Hope it helps

There are a bunch of answers in the question I linked as duplicate, including one that shows how placement of your Routes when using a wildcard (/{id}) matters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62608419/3965631. Also, in the future, don't put "SOLUTION" in your question; there is an answers section below where you can post your own answer.

This is happening cause /{id} and /history are same URL pattern, to solve this issue you need to pass regular expression constraints with where method :
Route::get('/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'show'])->where(['id' => '[0-9]+'])->name('show');
Route::get('/history', [GiveawayController::class, 'index'])->name('history');

So your final code will be like:
Route::prefix('giveaway')->name('giveaway.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'show'])->where(['id' => '[0-9]+'])->name('show');
    Route::post('/store/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
    Route::get('/thank-you', [GiveawayController::class, 'thankYou'])->name('thankYou');
    Route::get('/terms-and-conditions/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'privacyAndTerms'])->name('termsAndConditions');
    Route::get('/privacy-policy/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'privacyAndTerms'])->name('privacyPolicy');
    Route::get('/history', [GiveawayController::class, 'index'])->name('history');
});

See Laravel Routing Regular Expression Constraints
Without Regular Expression you can also solve it by defining the /history route  before /{id} route, (but this way is not recommended):
Route::get('/history', [GiveawayController::class, 'index'])->name('history');
Route::get('/{id}', [GiveawayController::class, 'show'])->name('show');


"but this way is not not recommended" - Curious about that part. I only ask since if you create a Route Resource (a commonly used official Laravel Routing approach), you get these Routes: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controllers, and the posts/{post} Route doesn't include a Regex, and simply comes after /posts/create to avoid the ambiguity. Navigating to /posts/history for example would in fact trigger a 404, and you'd have to define a /posts/history Route before Route::resource().

@TimLewis cause id is numeric value where history is alphabetical value. If the op has bot alphabetical value, then second way is recommend.  Anyway, this is my own opinion.

All good, and I realized after I asked that Laravel needs to be generic to support non-numeric values for /{post}, like UUIDs or Slugs, etc.
